# How to access RequestContext in class-based generic views?

Tags: django, django-generic-views, requestcontext, django-class-based-views

I have this path in my urls.py:

```
archive_index_dict = {
    'queryset': News.objects.filter(show=True),
    'date_field': 'date',
    'template_object_name': 'object_list',
}

...

url(r'^$', 'django.views.generic.date_based.archive_index',
        archive_index_dict, name='news_archive_index'
    ),
```

Now I want to detect in template if a page is current (this is for menu styling). Neither  `{{ request.path }}` nor `{{ request.get_full_path }}` work in template.

What should I use instead?

**SOLUTION**

To get `request` available in templates I had to add `django.core.context_processors.request` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`. This is not set by default (since django 1.3).

Comment: Do you have `django....request` context processor set up? Almost all CBV use `RequestContext` by default

Comment: OMG, of course not! :) Thank you for the hint, I've added `'django.core.context_processors.request'` in settings and `request` is available in templates now. BTW, you could post your comment as answer and I'd vote for it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do you have `'django.core.context_processors.request'` context processor set up? Almost all CBV use `RequestContext` by default

Comment: Could you add a reference? Like a link to docs/source where this is mentioned?

Comment: I think the question here was actually about the template context, independent of the view used. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I dug deep into the code, and it seems CBVs don't actually make the context object; they do however use the Template class, which uses make_context function that does (if it's passed a request)