# Getting RequestContext in auth_login and auth_logout

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-registration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access RequestContext in class-based generic views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162940/how-to-access-requestcontext-in-class-based-generic-views)

I am using django-registration, which uses the `django.contrib.auth.views.auth_login` and `django.contrib.auth.views.auth_login` views to provide login & logout. However, when it renders my registration/login.html and registration/logout.html templates, the `RequestContext` isn't included. What's the best way to get the `RequestContext` in these templates without monkey patching?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162940/how-to-access-requestcontext-in-class-based-generic-views

Answer (score 0):

Per Alex's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499070/getting-requestcontext-in-auth-login-and-auth-logout#comment16819928_12499070), adding the following worked:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    # ... other context processors here
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```